# Good math books to get on with my education?

Tags: soft-question, education, book-recommendation

im looking for a set of good math books.

Since i live in norway im going through the norwegian school system, where i choose to go whats called a electrical line. Im not gonna go to deep into the education system here, but the problem is that this "line" is primarily applied to by teenagers that dosnt do it to good in school. However i did do it quite good in school at junior high, and the math we have now is the same as we had during the first and second year of junior high. And i want to do some more advanced math, and after taking some tests i got an offer, but that offer had forced me to loose at least 3 hours of computer class, and maybe a couple of houres of automation, and in addition to that i would need to take the child math i already took. So i said no. However now that im trying to learn some fuctional programing(already have a solid fundation i imperative style) it would be nice to improve my math skills.

So does anyone have some good recomadations ?

https://www.regjeringen.no/en/topics/education/school/the-norwegian-education-system/id445118/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Norway

Comment: Personal advice questions are off-topic since they are too broad and likely to draw subjective answers. It would be a fine chatroom topic, though.

Answer (score 1):

I *loved* [this series](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s/?series_id=299892), as a child, especially ***How to count without counting***, ***Graphs and their uses***, and ***First concepts in topology***.  Of course, you will have your own taste in different topics, but these books are just wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

"What is Mathematics", by Courant.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just in grade 9, 10, 11 or 12, you really are not ready for things like combinatorics and topology.  I assume you know basic algebra and the easy parts of trigonometry. In that case, I would suggest you just use one book to work on your own, and the book I would try is Thomas and Finney's book Calculus and Analytic Geometry.  You can get it used for about \$20, and the skills you learn will surely be of use even if later you decide not to go further in math.

BTW, I love David's suggested books, I just think you may not be ready for them.

Comment: Nonsense I read topology in grade 9 and onwards.

Comment: Munkries is basically the standard intro book in topology.  Did you really work problems at that level when you were 13 or 14 years old? SOme people might have, but it is rare.

Comment: I had a copy of Topological methods in Euclidean spaces, by Gregory L. Naber.